# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.float64' and 'str'

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find standard deviation and mean from an input file (input.txt) which consists of 5000 data in one column and I want output in the file 'outfile.txt'. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy

from numpy import *

def main():
    outfile = open('outfile.txt','w')
    DataIn = loadtxt('input.txt')
    s = DataIn.std()
    m = DataIn.mean()
    outfile.write(s + '\n')
    outfile.write(m + '\n')
    outfile.close()

main()
```

When executed python 2.7.1, following message appeared: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.float64' and 'str'`

But, the following code worked well if output was printed on the screen in stead of output file:

```
import numpy
from numpy import *
DataIn = loadtxt('input.txt')
s = DataIn.std()
print s
```

Let me help to get the right code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
outfile.write(str(s) + '\n')
outfile.write(str(m) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

The first case fails because `s + '\n'` attempts to add two arguments of different types, and neither of the functions that can be used to implement this (`numpy.float64.__add__` and `str.__radd__`) know how to add a `numpy.float64` and a `str`. You have to be explicit, either calling `str` yourself with

```
outfile.write(str(s) + '\n')
```

or using a different function. Something like this would be preferable:

```
outfile.write( "{0}\n".format(s) )
```

The second case succeeds because the `print` statement implicit calls `str`) on each of the expressions passed to it, so it works as if you had written

```
print str(s)
```

The addition operator is not involved, so no undefined implicit conversions are necessary.

Note that the first case could work if `numpy.float64.__add__` were defined something like

```
def __add__(self, x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return str(self) + x
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific number of digits you would like your outputs to have? If so, replace the lines

```
outfile.write(s + '\n')
outfile.write(m + '\n')
```

with e.g.

```
outfile.write('{:1.4f}\n'.format(s))
outfile.write('{:1.4f}\n'.format(m))
```

This will give you numbers with 4 digits after the floating point. See [String formatting examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)